# Serialization of objects using WCF and Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Is there a way to hook into how specific types are serialized when using WCF and Silverlight.  For example, I need to tweak how System.DateTime properties are serialized/deserialized.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful here. Any time you change how something is serialized, you'll also have to change how the client deserializes it. You should have a very good reason in mind before changing how a data contract serializes, as they are made to be very interoperable. Anything you change could reduce the level of interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

In your datacontract, use the [OnSerialized] attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, Silverlight doesn't support serialization callbacks.  See my complaint <a href="http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2009/10/really-missing-serialization-callbacks.html">here</a>.

Answer (score 0):

Since Silverlight doesn't support serialization callbacks (see [here](http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2009/10/really-missing-serialization-callbacks.html)), you best bet might be to add a secondary property to any objects which wraps the DateTime property you need to control, and handle any "serialization" needs in that property.

Just a thought.